# understanding loop invariants

Tags: loops, loop-invariants

I have a bit of experience with loop invariants but I'm not really clear on them. I'm trying to learn them through an Algorithm I have.

```
Reverse(X,Y)
   n = X.length 
   for(i = 1 to n)
      Y[n - i + 1] = X[i] 
   return Y
```

This copies values in array X into array Y in reverse order, and returns array Y. If X and Y both have length n (i.e., n = X.length = Y.length) and both arrays are indexed from 1 to the length of the array, what would be some loop invariants for the for loop which would prove its correctness?

Comment: Please don't delete your question after receiving your answer.  An important part of our mission is to build up an archive of high-quality questions and answers that will be useful to others in the future.  Answerers might be answering on the basis that their answer will be useful not only to you but to others in the future.  Thus, deleting your question after you receive an answer can be considered impolite.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The reverse of `X[:i]`, the prefix of `X` up to the $i$-th position is equal to `Y[n-i+1:]`, the suffix of `Y` from the $(n-i+1)$-th position onward.

Before the loop starts, which we could consider as $i=0$, we have that the reverse of the prefix of `X` of length zero is equal to suffix of `Y` of length zero.

Each step of the loop preserves the property for the previous value of `i` and makes the property true for the current value of `i`.

At the end of the loop the property is satisfied for `i=n`, which implies that the reverse of `X` is equal to `Y`.